# Translate torch code intended for GPU computation to run on CPU only

Tags: pytorch, cpu

I have a pytorch-based code that runs on GPU due to his multiple calls to CUDA, the code is intended for object detection and the model has already been trained to do this. So what I do is testing a model on a dataset. However, my GPU is not enough powerful to make the model run without Out Of Memory (OOM) errors.

My GPU is Nvidia P400 and I set up cuda 9.0 for it. I'm running on the 396.54 Nvidia driver version. I didn't try to upgrade it because it causes troubles to my settings. My operating system is Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

More specifically, my question is the following. In order to make my pytorch code run on CPU, can I just remove the occurrence of `cuda` in my code ?
For example replacing this following code :

```
torch.cuda.manual_seed(11)
```

By

```
torch.manual_seed(11)
```

EDIT :
When I set up pytorch on my conda environment, I installed a gpu compatible pytorch.
So now that I tried to remove all the occurrences of cuda, it doesn't work and I get the following error :

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=74 error=38 : no CUDA-capable device is detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1111, in <module>
    train()
  File "main.py", line 1039, in train
    log_path=model_save_path)
  File "main.py", line 858, in train_networks
    train_losses, valid_losses, test_losses = pickle.load(lossfile, encoding='latin1')
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/pytorch-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 492, in _lazy_new
    _lazy_init()
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/pytorch-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 161, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:7
```

Comment: did you also consider lines where you move your model and data to the corresponding device? Those are not necessarily highlighted with `.cuda` in their respective function names, see [`.to_device()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html)

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the code. But, from the trace you have provided, it seems that the objects `train_losses`, `valid_losses` and `test_losses` might be stored as instances of type `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`, thus when you load them from the file `lossfile`, PyTorch tries to put them on the GPU and can't find an appropriate cuda device (maybe drivers/cudnn missing?) to load them.